# Attributing Value on One List to Another List

Tags: python

I am writing a loop that pulls data from different sheet names and then plots this data. The sheet names are denote in the code listed below as 'sheetnames'. Each sheet name goes along with a number in the list 'ts' shown below. When I plot going through the loop, I need the x-value to be the value in the 'ts' that corresponds to the 'sheetname'. For the first one, before I put this in a loop I was able to put a '0' in for the x-value, but I obviously cannot do that anymore since the value is only 0 for the first sheet. My full code is very long, but below is 'sheetnames', 'ts', and the information for my plot. Note that the data contained in sheetnames is simply the sheet that my code pulls data from in an excel file. If there's any more information needed, I can update it with additional code.

```
sheetnames = ['0h UV Exposure, Roll Direction', 
          '4h UV Exposure, Roll Direction', 
          '8h UV Exposure, Roll Direction', 
          '12h UV Exposure, Roll Direction', 
          '18h UV Exposure, Roll Direction', 
          '24h UV Exposure, Roll Direction', 
          '36h UV Exposure, Roll Direction', 
          '48h UV Exposure, Roll Direction', 
          '68h UV Exposure, Roll Direction', 
          '78h UV Exposure, Roll Direction', 
          '82h UV Exposure, Roll Direction', 
          '96h UV Exposure, Roll Direction'] 

ts = [0,4,8,12,18,24,36,48,68,78,82,96]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(0,Average_Toughness,'ro')
plt.xlabel('Time (Hours)')
plt.ylabel('Toughness')
plt.title('Toughness Plot')
```

Comment: We don't know what `Average_Toughness` is. Please give a full reproducible sample of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of itereating over `sheetnames` directly, you can use `range()` to iterate over the list *positions*, and then access the current position item in both lists:

```
for pos in range(len(sheetnames)):
    # now you can use sheetnames[pos] and ts[pos]
```